# Relation between static Nash equlibria and dynamic equlibria

Tags: gt.game-theory, dynamic-algorithms

I am working on Normal form continuous games. I am not very familiar with dynamic game theory. I would like to know if there is any relation between static Nash equilibria and dynamic equilibria. If players play a certain game repeatedly or learn about the strategies of the players or if they follow certain dynamics, will they always converge to static Nash equilibria?

Is there any result between set of static Nash equilibria and dynamic equlibria (under some conditions)? Thanks in advance!